# Can a garage slab pour be done in multiple sections?

Tags: concrete, garage

My wife and I just bought a house that has a detached 3 car garage. It has gravel floors and we would like to upgrade to concrete. What would be the recommendation here. I am thinking use a skid steer to get it level then a 4" pour of 3,000 psi concrete. Could this be broken into 3 pours like forming one bay up and pouring then having a second pour at stall 2 and so on or just one pour at one time? Can I pour right on top of the existing gravel after leveling or should I put a vapor barrier down?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be a good idea, and further, to use expansion joints (3/4" strip of material along edge) and re-bar.  Do you have any aspiration to heat the garage?

Comment: You're asking several distinct questions here, all of which have been covered already on this site. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Ask just one clear question in a post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pouring a concrete slab in batches](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/272655/pouring-a-concrete-slab-in-batches)

Comment: Be aware that nearly all such slabs are worked with power trowels these days--big machines like an upside-down ceiling fan. You won't get nearly as flat a slab without that, especially as a novice. Also, a garage slab should usually be shaped and sloped to direct water to the door. That's easier said than done if you don't want dizzying slopes. This is a rare case where I strongly advise that a skilled professional do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST have a vapor barrier. Period. Clean out the old gravl as you indicated. Lay down the vapor barrier. I'd do it in 3 sections. Make sure you use rebar or something for strength. Good luck.

Comment: In a _garage_? I've never once seen that. What's the purpose?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: isherwood... the vapor barrier goes in first. I don't know what to say. Don't take my word for it. I've done concrete work since I was very young and you need to have it. I've got relatives who run concrete/flatwor/block businesses... that's the right way to go.

I can't post a google search but search this: vapor barrier under concrete slab